# Alternate between printing two series of numbers

Tags: python-3.x

Input format: The first line of input consists of the number of test cases, T

Next T lines consist of the value of N.

Constraints: 1<= T <=100, 1<= N <= 250

Output format: For each test case, print the space-separated N terms of the series in a separate line.

## Sample test case 1

Input:

```
1
7
```

Output:

```
1 1 2 2 4 2 6
```

The series is a combination of 2 series, the 1st series: 1,2,4,6,... and the 2nd series: 1,2,2,.... I have made the code for the first series but cannot find how to code the 2nd one.

## Code for the first series appended into list depending on the no of elements

```
def firstS:
    l=[1]
    i=1
    x=math.ceil(7/2)
    while(x!=0):
        l.append(i+i)
        i+=1
        x-=1
    return l
```

The problem is the no of elements, for 7 elements the 1st series has 4 and 2nd series has 3 elements, for 8 elements 1st has 4 and 2nd has 4 elements and for 9 elements 1st has 5 and 2nd has 4 elements so the no of elements will be for series 1 `math.ceil(n/2)` and for series 2 `math.floor(n/2)` where n is total elements of the combined series.

Comment: Can you add more tags, your are rather looking for algorithm to solution not just a pythonic solution.

Comment: What exactly are 1st the 2nd series'? Is the first one just the even number, if it is then what is 1 doing there? and what is the 2nd series? 1, 2, 2.. what will be the sequence after that?

Comment: @Kaushal yes i am looking for an algorithm if there is one, till then i am assuming it to be combination of 2 series

Comment: @lprakashv the first series is an AP with and extra term '1' added in the start, which i know doesnt make sense but its the only solution i was able to come up with, and second one should be 1,22,333,4444,........ and i am assuming them to be series they could be whole another algorithm that i dont know about

Answer (score 0):

For iteration, one way do something every `N` iterations is to use the modulus operator (`%`). Modulus is basically a remainder operator, so the result periodically repeats as numbers are iterated one-by-one.

Also, in Python, the standard method for doing a for-loop (iterating a certain number of times) is using [range](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range).

Here's an example demonstrating both, where every third number has the same number of exclamation marks:

```
# List the numbers 0-9 (repeat ten times)
for i in range(0, 10):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print(i, "!")
    elif i % 3 == 1:
        print(i, "!!")
    else:
        print(i, "!!!")
```

Result:

```
0 !
1 !!
2 !!!
3 !
4 !!
5 !!!
6 !
7 !!
8 !!!
9 !
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for the asker to determine how to apply this to their use-case of switching between printing two different sequences.